# 2017 MacBook Pro can't connect to Dell P2715Q via USB-C to DisplayPort cable

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, displayport, 4k

I purchased a [USB-C to DisplayPort cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N6R3E0W) from Amazon to connect my 2017 MacBook Pro to a Dell 2715Q however it does not seem to be working.

From what I've read and from some of the cable reviews, there shouldn't be an issue yet my MacBook does not recognize the display. The monitor seems to know that it is connected to a device and shows a message saying that there is no signal coming from the computer.

Is it possible that there is some setup I need to do, or is there a compatibility issue between the display and cable? Or is it possible the cable is no good? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried multiple ports on your computer? Does the computer recognize that a cord is plugged into it? (Does the screen flicker to black when you plug it in and unplug it?) Based on your description, it sounds to me like a connection problem between the MBP and the cable

Comment: I'm using this one and it's working: https://www.amazon.com/Plugable-DisplayPort-1-8m-Chromebook-Thunderbolt/dp/B01EXKDRAC

Comment: @NoahL Yeah, I've tried different ports and there is no flicker when I plug the cable in, but I'm not sure If the MacBook isn't detecting the cable or if there a problem with the cable itself.

Comment: My thoughts would then be to try another cable (don't return that one just yet, try to use another one you already have). If a different cable still doesn't work, try reseting the NVRAM (and maybe the SMC).

Comment: Same issue here, bought an [USB C to Fullsize Displayport](https://www.conrad.de/de/usb-vga-anschlusskabel-1x-usb-c-stecker-1x-displayport-stecker-180-m-schwarz-renkforce-1528057.html) cable.
Got two MacBook Pro 2017 (15 Inch Touchbar) try to connect to an Dell UP3216Q, did not work.
Got two MacBook Pro Late 2016 (15 Inch Touchbar) same Monitor and cable, everything works fine.

Comment: This is due DisplayPort 1.2 support missing or turned off on the monitor side. Some monitors allow to turn it on. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/319870/2017-mac-cannot-connect-the-monitor-via-usb-c-to-displayport-cable?noredirect=1#comment407169_319870

Answer (score 3):

I used the [Star Tech USB to DisplayPort Cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01EZH7CKO) to a similar model monitor, and it worked.

On 1 monitor I had to manually [change the DP version](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN296015/how-to-solve-the-dp-mini-dp-no-video--wrong-resolution-issue-with-the-dell-p2715q-p2415q-flat-panel-monitors?lang=EN).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Answer (score 2):

On my old monitor Dell U3014, I needed to go to the settings of the monitor (not the laptop) and turn on the DisplayPort 1.2 support which is for some reason disabled by default. To make things worse, the local menu (and not just the input source) on this monitor becomes available only after some valid signal is already coming. Connect some other video source temporarily to it.

My mac is MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017), OS 10.13.3 (17D102), cable Delock 85256 USB C.  The display is Dell U3014, it worked fine with various computers for many years and still does.

HDMI to USB C adapter works with this monitor out of box but for some reason produces really low quality image (something wrong with colours).

Summarising, DisplayPort 1.2 must be supported by the cable and monitor, and also activated on the monitor side.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and after it driving me to the brink of insanity for a couple of weeks, trying all different methods and losing tons of time, I found this:
[https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-DisplayPort-Adapter-Thunderbolt/dp/B01K51GM46/ref=sr_1_21?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1501663062&sr=1-21&keywords=macbook+pro+displayport+2017](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01K51GM46)

So, Apple basically changed the 2017 version in some way compared to the 2016 one. The support guys didnt know about that, but luckily some 3rd party vendors has managed to catch up..